# How do search engines implement fuzzy search?

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, search-algorithms

Googling "large horse walks into house" also returns results that contain "large horse in a house" and "the house has large horses".

How is Google able to return near-matches and not just direct matches?

What are the methods that search engines use to perform such queries so quickly?

I know about [phrase search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrase_search) and [proximity search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proximity_search_(text)) and how they can be implemented using a positional inverted index, but this is neither a phrase search (because the terms don't have to be directly adjacent nor in order) nor proximity search (because the terms don't have to be in order nor within a fixed width of each other — nor all present)

It seems like somehow these search engines are doing a string edit distance lookup across billions of documents in fractions of a second.

How have they managed to implement this kind of searching on top of an index?

Comment: I think the answer to this question is a textbook. For your own research, you may try and find out how tools like ElasticSearch work. Most likely, in practice, the correct answer is a combination of clever distributed algorithms/data structures, selectively applied AI/ML techniques, and raw processing power.